# How to save a random string from a list of strings?

Tags: python, random

How do I save a random string from a list so I can recall the exact thing later in the code? For example:

```
name = ['Hans', 'Peter', 'Eliza']
print('Your name is ' + random(name) + '!')
print(name)
```

What can I use here in place of `random(name)`, and how can I save it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) method from the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module:

```
import random

name = ['Hans', 'Peter', 'Eliza']
print('Your name is ' + random.choice(name) + '!')
```

> ```
> random.choice(seq)
>     Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq.
>     If seq is empty, raises IndexError.
> ```

Also, I would use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead:

```
import random

name = ['Hans', 'Peter', 'Eliza']
print('Your name is {}!'.format(random.choice(name)))
```

I missed the part about *saving* the value. That can be done like this:

```
name = ['Hans', 'Peter', 'Eliza']
random_name = random.choice(name)

print('Your name is {}!'.format(random_name))
```

Comment: enemy = ['Zombie', 'Dragon', 'Warrior']
 print('A ' + random.choice(enemy) + ' appeared!\nHealth ' + str(enemystats[0]) + '\nAttack Damage ' + str(enemystats[1]) + '\nInitiative ' + str(enemystats[2]))  print('The ' + enemy + ' attacked you!')
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: Hmm?

    `In [10]: print('Your name is ' + random.choice(name) + '!')`
    `Your name is Hans!`

`random.choice()` will only return one element of a list. Added a note about `str.format()` just in case.

Comment: With the code that I send above. How would I do that?

Comment: I want to save the enemy name (Zombie, Dragon or Warrior) which will be randomly selected and then re-use the name in the variable so I can call it later with : print('The ' + enemy + 'attacked you!')

Comment: Ah, got it. See my edit in the answer. The error you were seeing about concatenating strings and lists shouldn't happen if your `enemystats` list is just a flat list. If it's a list of lists, or a list of other objects, you can't print them in that way (convert to string using `' '.join(my_list)`).

Comment: PERFECT THANK YOU SO MUCH <3

Comment: Awesome, no problem, glad to help! :) Please click the "Accept Answer" checkbox if this solves the problem. Thanks!